# Defining no data in qml style file or python for QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis, gdal, qml

I am attempting to script a process that I undertake quite frequently, and have got everything working apart from one little step.

Essentially I want to convert a singleband raster into a 3 band geotiff based on a qml style file.

This is working, apart from the fact that No Data needs to be displayed as 255,0,255. If for example the No Data value is 15, I define this in the symbology, but the qml doesn't save the checkbox "No data value" setting which needs to be unchecked in order to display the no data. As a result, my 3 band geotiff displays no data as black instead of pink.

I was wondering if there is a way to integrate this step into my script? I use the python-qgis.bat file from OSGEO4w in C:\OSGeo4W64\bin to run this in command prompt.

Below is the script that exports as rendered image based on my style file, then removes 4th band that is created.

`import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
app = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
rasterpath = "C:\Users\folderpath\1bandraster.tif"
layer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterpath, "rastername")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
uri = "C:\Users\folderpath\stylefile.qml"
layer.loadNamedStyle(uri)
extent = layer.extent()
width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider=layer.dataProvider()
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('C:\Users\folderpath\4bandraster.tif')
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                       width,
                       height,
                       extent,
                       layer.crs())
import os
os.system('gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -of GTiff -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 C:\Users\folderpath\4bandraster.tif C:\Users\folderpath\OUTPUT-3band.tif’)`

[[image: checkbox that is needed to be unchecked in order to visualise no data value[1]]
[image: desired symbology (15 is no data value)]

Comment: Not exactly sure but maybe one of  "no data" methods in the QgsRasterBlock will work, https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Raster/QgsRasterBlock.html

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully it's ok to answer my own question after I've asked it.

I found that adding the following code solved my problem of NoData not displaying in the 255,0,255 colour that I defined. I specify the value in each band as follows:

```
provider.setNoDataValue(1, 255) 
provider.setNoDataValue(2, 0) 
provider.setNoDataValue(3, 255) 
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

So successful code is as follows:

```
import qgis
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
app = QApplication([], True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
rasterpath = "C:\Users\folderpath\1bandraster.tif"
layer = QgsRasterLayer(rasterpath, "rastername")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
uri = "C:\Users\folderpath\stylefile.qml"
layer.loadNamedStyle(uri)
extent = layer.extent()
width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
renderer = layer.renderer()
provider=layer.dataProvider()
provider.setNoDataValue(1, 255) 
provider.setNoDataValue(2, 0) 
provider.setNoDataValue(3, 255) 
layer.triggerRepaint()
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
pipe.set(provider.clone())
pipe.set(renderer.clone())
file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter('C:\Users\folderpath\4bandraster.tif')
file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                       width,
                       height,
                       extent,
                       layer.crs())
import os
os.system('gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -of GTiff -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 C:\Users\folderpath\4bandraster.tif C:\Users\folderpath\OUTPUT-3band.tif’)
```